# How to shift ham burger icon to right in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I have a toolbar and navigation drawer activity in android. Now I want to shift ham burger icon (navigation drawer icon) to right side of toolbar. initially the icon is on left but I want to shift it on right. So, how can I.

Comment: Please remember that such questions would rarely fetch any answers. You need to show what you have done. Show some code. Give much details. Only then people would be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If you use DrawerLayout you should call openDrawer() with `Gravity.END`.

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own navigation hamburger button.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   >

   <ImageButton
       android:layout_gravity="end"
       android:src="@drawable/your_ham_burger_icon"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```